# R- display slope of regression line on graph

Tags: r

I would like to display the slope of the line of best fit onto the chart.
I know annotate(geom='text',x=#,y=#) is for displaying the value

but how do I get the slope ? Can this be boxed and having an arrow point at the line ? (Latter is optional if it's too much work) I can do this on Tableau but I am new to R

```
library(lattice)
vals<-data.frame(x=1:10,y=(1:10)^2)
xyplot(x~y,data=vals,type=c("p","r"))
```

Thank you much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this done in ggplot with an an extension package called [`ggpmisc`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggpmisc/versions/0.3.5). It will add the regression line and R^2 value to your plot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
vals <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = (1:10)^2)
vals %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
   stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x, aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), parse = TRUE)
```

This will print the equation and the R^2 value of the best fit line on your plot. However if you just want to display slope and not the equation I'm not quite sure how to do that. You can find the documentation for this particular function [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggpmisc/versions/0.3.5/topics/stat_poly_eq). Hope this helps!

Comment: I am not seeing the line equation!